# Why is 211 used in plt.subplot(211)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the pyplot documentation I saw

plt.subplt(211) which is identical to subplot(2, 1, 1)

I've also seen 211 being used elsewhere. Why specifically are those numbers being used as opposed to other ones?

Comment: Because they mean the same thing and you don't need to type as many commas?  Seriously, IMHO, this is one case where I think that matplotlib tried to get too clever with it's API (it definitely violates TOOWTDI)...

Comment: Maybe this feature was inspired from octave (which tries to be compatible to MatLab).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html#Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page  (look at the 2nd option "rcn": a 3-digit integer).

Comment: Thanks. I guess it doesn't matter what the number is then. There's nothing special about that number. It seems someone chose that number and then others kept with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`plt.subplot` takes three arguments, the number of rows (`nrows`), the number of columns (`ncols`) and the plot number. Using the 3-digit code is a convenience function provided for when `nrows`, `ncols` and `plot_number` are all `<10`.

So, `211` is equivalent to `nrows=2`, `ncols=1`, `plot_number=1`.

[From the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot):

> Return a subplot axes positioned by the given grid definition.
>
> Typical call signature:
>
> ```
> subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)
> ```
>
> Where nrows and ncols are used to
>   notionally split the figure into `nrows * ncols` sub-axes, and
>   `plot_number` is used to identify the particular subplot that this
>   function is to create within the notional grid. `plot_number` starts at
>   1, increments across rows first and has a maximum of `nrows * ncols`.
>
> In the case when `nrows`, `ncols` and `plot_number` are all less than 10, a
>   convenience exists, such that the a 3 digit number can be given
>   instead, where the hundreds represent `nrows`, the tens represent `ncols`
>   and the units represent `plot_number`. For instance:
>
> ```
> subplot(211)
> ```
>
> produces a subaxes in a figure which represents the top
>   plot (i.e. the first) in a 2 row by 1 column notional grid (no grid
>   actually exists, but conceptually this is how the returned subplot has
>   been positioned).

Comment: Thanks this is a very good explanation and I understand it much better now.